# Execute Reader wait operation time out error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, executereader

stuck on this since few days please help. I have tried a lot of solutions like increase connection timeout in web config: below is my error code.

```
    Server Error in '/' Application.

The wait operation timed out
```

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out
```

Source Error:

```
Line 595:        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
Line 596:        con.Open();
Line 597:        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
Line 598:        //cs.CloseConnection();
Line 599:        return rd;

Source File: c:\inetpub\vhosts\xyz.com\httpdocs\App_Code\admin.cs    Line: 597
```

Stack Trace:

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out]

[SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1789294
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5340642
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +244
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1691
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +61
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +90
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +377
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds) +1421
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +177
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +53
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +137
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader() +99
   admin.GetDatareader(String str) in c:\inetpub\vhosts\YXZ.com\httpdocs\App_Code\admin.cs:597
   subcategories.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\vhosts\XYZ.com\httpdocs\shop.aspx.cs:440
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34274
```

Comment: Check query that is executing, maybe it _really_ takes too long like 10 minutes. If thats the case - you may want to add some indexes to tables or improve query perf in other ways (rewrite it?)

Answer (score 7):

Try by assigning 0 to the command timeout as below. A value of 0 indicates no limit (an attempt to execute a command will wait indefinitely). If its still timing out, optimize the stored procedure.

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
    con.Open();
    rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set command timeout as below:

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
 cmd.CommandTimeout = 480;
 con.Open();
 rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Note: along with timeout configuration, you also need to improve the performance of related SQL.